# Do I use "the" or "a"? How do I decide which article to use?

Tags: articles

Do I need to put "the" in front of correlation and negative?

> We performed a correlation analysis to measure **a** correlation between job satisfaction and the shortage of nursing. We found that **a** negative correlation between job satisfaction and the shortage of nursing was indicated.

Comment: I would say "measure any correlation" and "found that a negative correlation" myself, but "a" is ok in both cases. *The* is not really right in this example.

Comment: Personally I think ***the*** is more appropriate for the first instance. It slightly implies that there *was already known to be* such a correlation - but since this was discovered to be true anyway, that's not unreasonable. It's entirely a matter of stylistic preference whether to include the second ***a*** or not, but if OP is concerned about "style", I suggest using "correlation" less than three times would be a good place to start.

Comment: In your sentences, the first is ***the*** because it's a specific correlation; the second is ***a*** because it's an example of a negative correlation.

Answer (score 2):

**the** correlation between........appears appropriate simply because of the coorelation being specific in its study between job satisfaction and the shortage of nursing.

**a** negative correlation ..........would refer to some/any coorelation that could have been derived.

Too wordy, though.